# Java OAuth2 Provider Implementation | Custom Errors

Tags: java, oauth, custom-errors

I have searched high and low for the answer to this question and now I'm reaching out to the community.

- I'm trying to build an OAuth2 access token endpoint in Java.
- I'll be implementing the resource owner credentials grant type to return an access token. (specifying end-user's username/password to get an access token)
- During authentication of the user credentials, a number of rules could prevent the user from having access to my web service, such as the user account being locked.
- The OAuth2 [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) says that errors must be returned as follows:

  `{ "error":"invalid_request", "error_description":"description", "error_uri":"some_link" }`
- It's also my understanding that the OAuth spec lists standard error codes and that you should avoid custom `error` codes in the response, like `{"error":"account_locked"}`; however, I've seen some API providers do this.
- I need the clients of this API to be able to read an error code in the response to know when the account is locked. (or other specific scenarios)

  **Now my questions are:**
- Does anyone here have the experience to suggest how should this scenario be implemented?
- Should I implement custom error codes?
- Should I forget the OAuth2 spec and just build a `/token` endpoint that does the same thing: authenticates the user, generates the token, and returns my API's standard error response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't have an exactly same senario. But I won't use custom error codes since it violates OAuth2. Instead, I may consider using the "error_description" as the error-code field in this case; Or I can add an biz_error_code field.
2. Yes, you can forget OAuth2, which is not flexible in terms of http status code and error_code. But you will end up building something very similar with OAuth2's 'password' grant_type, such as an access token and a refresh token.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. #2 is what I did in the end.